# MongoDB — Which Authentication Database should I use when creating users

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, admin, user-management

In Current Mongo Instance

Following the Mongo Best Practices : Users are created in system database(Admin) rather than respective database and made admin database as authorization database

But creating users in system database (admin) works fine when tested in standalone functions when checked with code(Docker) getting exceptions

Also before creating user used the command

switch to admin

connection string used:

```
mongodb:// :@xxxxxxx:27017/admin
```

> Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with
> error 263 (OperationNotSupportedInTransaction):  'Cannot run command
> against the 'admin' database in a transaction.' on server xxxxxxxxxxx.
> The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t":
> 1649307185, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Cannot run command against
> the 'admin' database in a transaction.",  "code": 263, "codeName":
> "OperationNotSupportedInTransaction", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime":
> {"$timestamp": {"t": 1649307185, "i": 1}},  "signature": {"hash":
> {"$binary": {"base64": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "subType":
> "00"}}, "keyId": 0}}}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My doubt is while creating database user in Mongo DB. What is the best database can be used for authentication database. whether I should use 'admin' database or specifically create the user in the actual database which I am using

Comment: I don't see any reason to create users in any other database than `admin`. Maybe the only exception is, when you provide a mongo playground like https://mongoplayground.net/ to your users.